# Magento 2.3 folder structure of the Catalog Product List widget

Tags: magento2, widget

I am using Magento 2.3.3 and I am looking for the folder structure of the Catalog Product List widget in order to look at the code. I have tried searching the /var/www/html/vendor/magento folders but haven't found it.

Comment: Hi, which widget do you mean exactly? There are a few around product listing such as recently viewed etc. Could you please describe how this widget is added to your shop. Thanks.

Comment: you can check at : vendor/module-catalog-widget folder

Comment: The widget is listed as Catalog Product List.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The widget definition happens in a widget.xml in this case `vendor/magento/module-catalog-widget/etc/widget.xml`.

Here you can see the class defined as `Magento\CatalogWidget\Block\Product\ProductsList`

It is also defined as the default template as `Magento_CatalogWidget::product/widget/content/grid.phtml`